# Get FileNotFoundException in EAR on Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

What could cause this?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data1/applications/payara-5.2022.5/glassfish/domains/web-cls-sample-event-tracking/applications/cls-sample-event-tracking-ear-4.0.2/jta-1.0.1B.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:231)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:157)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:169)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:106)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm deploying an EAR and I had this in one project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1B</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this in another my root project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```